# Animation of figure with subplots using VideoWriter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, animation, matlab-figure, subplot

I'm trying to create an animation file in MATLAB from a figure with 2 subplots using the `VideoWriter`. However, the avi file that I get includes only one of the subplots.

Here is the code:

```
clc    
clear 
vidObj = VideoWriter('randdata');   
open(vidObj)    
figure (1)   
for i = 1:100       
    clf        
    subplot(1,2,1)        
    imagesc(rand(100))        
    subplot(1,2,2)        
    imagesc(rand(100))       
    drawnow       
    CF = getframe;        
    writeVideo(vidObj,CF);        
end
```

There must be something simple going wrong here but I don't know what. I would like to capture the entire figure.

Comment: It is easier if you do a gif animation ;)

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for `getframe`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) states in the first line:

> F = getframe captures the current **axes**

So it's capturing the axes, not figure.

You want to use it as also specified in the documentation

> F = getframe(fig) captures the figure identified by fig. **Specify a figure if you want to capture the entire interior of the figure window**, including the axes title, labels, and tick marks. The captured movie frame does not include the figure menu and tool bars.

So your code should be

```
clc; clear
vidObj = VideoWriter('randdata');
open(vidObj);
figure(1);
for ii = 1:100
    clf
    subplot(1,2,1)
    imagesc(rand(100))
    subplot(1,2,2)
    imagesc(rand(100))
    drawnow;
    % The gcf is key. You could have also used 'f = figure' earlier, and getframe(f)
    CF = getframe(gcf); 
    writeVideo(vidObj,CF);
end
```

---

For ease, you might want to just get a File Exchange function like the popular (and simple) [`gif`](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63239-gif) to create an animated gif.